# Java Android app java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.graphics.FontFamily.<init> []

Tags: java, android, exception, nosuchmethoderror

I get a exception when i try to run my android app that i created with android studio and java. It doesnt look like that it breakes my app, but it shows everty time in my console.

```
    W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
W/.koen.dirkpane: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/.koen.dirkpane: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
E/TypefaceCompatApi26Impl: Unable to collect necessary methods for class java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.graphics.FontFamily.<init> []
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
        at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.obtainFontFamilyCtor(TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.java:321)
        at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.<init>(TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.java:84)
        at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi28Impl.<init>(TypefaceCompatApi28Impl.java:36)
        at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.<clinit>(TypefaceCompat.java:47)
        at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.create(TypefaceCompat.java:190)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
        at android.widget.TextView.resolveStyleAndSetTypeface(TextView.java:2183)
        at android.widget.TextView.setTypefaceFromAttrs(TextView.java:2154)
        at android.widget.TextView.applyTextAppearance(TextView.java:4105)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1630)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:990)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:99)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:95)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1059)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.koen.dirkpanel.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7995)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7979)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Does anyone might have an idea what causes it and how i can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check your layout, do you have a scrollView or any other view that can only have 1 child with more than one child?

Comment: do u got any solution

Answer (score 5):

You can use `androidx.core` dependency to avoid this crash

```
dependencies {
   def core_version = "1.3.2"
   
   // Java language implementation
   implementation "androidx.core:core:$core_version"

   // Kotlin
   implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$core_version"

   ...
}
```

Read more about [androidx.core](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the latest core library in your build.gradle

implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.1'